# Binding to a read-only property in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a model type which looks like this:

```
enum State {
    case loading
    case loaded([String])
    case failed(Error)

    var strings: [String]? {
        switch self {
        case .loaded(let strings): return strings
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

class MyApi: ObservableObject {
    private(set) var state: State = .loading

    func fetch() {
        ... some time later ...
        self.state = .loaded(["Hello", "World"])
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use this to drive a SwiftUI View.

```
struct WordListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var api: MyApi

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List($api.state.strings) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's about here that my assumptions fail. I'm trying to get a list of the strings to render in my `List` when they are loaded, but it won't compile.

The compiler error is `Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred`, which after a bit of googling tells me that bindings are two-way, so won't work with both my `private(set)` and the var on the State enum being read-only.

This doesn't seem to make any sense - there is no way that the view should be able to tell the api whether or not it's loading, that definitely should be a one-way data flow!

I guess my question is either

1. Is there a way to get a one-way binding in SwiftUI - i.e. some of the UI will update based on a value it cannot change.

or

2. How should I have architected this code! It's very likely that I'm writing code in a style which doesn't work with SwiftUI, but all the tutorials I can see online neatly ignore things like loading / error states.

Comment: List does not require binding, why do you use `List($api.state.strings)` instead of, I'd expect, `List(api.state.strings)`?

Comment: Because (a) I'm new to SwiftUI and (b) when I do that it didn't update the UI. Should it have done?

Comment: I would do, and make `state` as `@Published` to have view updated

Comment: @Asperi You should have made this an answer so I could tick it :) I didn't realise that any changes to an observable object would trigger a redraw even if they weren't a binding. Working perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't actually need a binding for this.

An intuitive way to decide if you need a binding or not is to ask:

> *Does this view need to modify the passed value ?*

In your case the answer is no. The `List` doesn't need to modify `api.state` (as opposed to a textfield or a slider for example), it just needs the current value of it at any given moment. That is what `@State` is for *but* since the state is not something that *belongs* to the view (remember, Apple says that each state must be private to the view) you're correctly using some form of an `ObservableObject` (through Environment).

The final missing piece is to mark any of your properties that should trigger an update with `@Published`, which is a convenience to fire `objectWillChange` signals and instruct any observing view to recalculate its body.

So, something like this will get things done:

```
class MyApi: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var state: State = .loading

    func fetch() {
        self.state = .loaded(["Hello", "World"])
    }
}

struct WordListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var api: MyApi

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List(api.state.strings ?? [], id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if instead of `MyApi` we have some @Published value-type property that comes from somewhere but needs to be observed within our custom view?

Comment: It depends on what this "somewhere" actually is and _where_ it is captured.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same problem as I had, but the following direction can help you possibly find a good result when bindings are done with only reads.

You can create a custom binding using a computed property.

I needed to do exactly this in order to show an alert only when one was passed into an overlay.

Code looks something along these lines :

```
struct AlertState {
    var title: String
}

class AlertModel: ObservableObject {

    // Pass a binding to an alert state that can be changed at
    // any time.
    @Published var alertState: AlertState? = nil
    @Published var showAlert: Bool = false

    init(alertState: AnyPublisher<AlertState?, Never>) {
        alertState
            .assign(to: &$alertState)

        alertState
            .map { $0 != nil }
            .assign(to: &$showAlert)
    }
}

struct AlertOverlay<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content
    @ObservedObject var alertModel: AlertModel

    init(
        alertModel: AlertModel,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.alertModel = alertModel
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .blur(radius: alertModel.showAlert
                      ? UserInterfaceStandards.blurRadius
                      : 0)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $alertModel.showAlert) {
            guard let alertState = alertModel.alertState else {
                return Alert(title: Text("Unexected internal error as occured."))
            }
            return Alert(title: Text(alertState.title))
        }
    }
}
```